# How to save data in internal or external directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sensors

java.io.IOException: No such file or Directory

I wanna save sensors data in a .csv data and always i receive this error. Can anybody help ???

```
 fun onStop(view: View){

    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
    val fileName = "Accelerometer $time.csv"
    var data = _accelerometerStringBuilder.toString()

  
   
    var fileWriter: FileWriter? = null

    var myExFile = File(getExternalFilesDir("/storage/emulated/0"),fileName)
    File.createTempFile("Accelerometer $time", "csv", myExFile)

    fileWriter = FileWriter(fileName)
    fileWriter.appendLine(CSV_HEADER)
    fileWriter.appendLine(data)
    fileWriter.close()


    var myExternalFile2:File = File(getExternalFilesDir("/storage/emulated/0"),"Gyroscope $time.csv")
    File.createTempFile("Gyroscope $time", "csv", myExternalFile2)

    fileWriter = FileWriter("Gyroscope $time.csv")
    fileWriter.appendLine(CSV_HEADER)
    fileWriter.appendLine(_gyroscopeStringBuilder.toString())
    fileWriter.close()


}
```

Comment: `java.io.IOException: No such file or Directory` Bad message. About which file or directory is this? Tell full path please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
fun onStop(view: View) {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this)
        val fileAcc = File(PathUtils.getExternalAppFilesPath(),"Accelerometer $time.csv")
        FileIOUtils.writeFileFromString(fileAcc,_accelerometerStringBuilder.toString(),true)
        FileIOUtils.writeFileFromString(fileAcc,CSV_HEADER,true)

        val fileGyro = File(PathUtils.getExternalAppFilesPath(),"Gyroscope $time.csv")
        FileIOUtils.writeFileFromString(fileGyro,_gyroscopeStringBuilder.toString(),true)
        FileIOUtils.writeFileFromString(fileGyro,CSV_HEADER,true)
    }
```

This library make thing easier : `implementation 'com.blankj:utilcodex:1.29.0'`

Permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

To ensure the files are successfully created, go to your phone > File Manager App > Search bar > Search for time.csv and you will see the created files there

Comment: I've had the premissions, the Problem is, the getExternal AppFilesPath() is not possible to Import from library.

Comment: `PathUtils.getExternalAppFilesPath()` is from `implementation 'com.blankj:utilcodex:1.29.0'` library make sure to import it correctly

Comment: I did it. als aos the library is there, because i could Import PathUtils and FileIOUtils. just getExternalAppfilesPath() doesn't work, although there is in my Import library path

Comment: Thank you Mouaad, it works now. Do you know also About the String.format ?

Comment: the numbers appears as 0.034.234.234.234 , the first "." should be "," for me but I don't see any model to Format it.

Comment: @AAA Glade to hear that, if my answer worked for you please make it as acceptable answer, for your question, I will gladly help you, just create a new question here in stackoverflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63903748/how-to-change-the-format-of-numbers-in-csv-data-kotlin

Comment: @AAA I've answered your question