# how to change the format of numbers in .csv data Kotlin

Tags: string, android-studio, kotlin, string-formatting

I receive the data from sensors and save it in an .csv file. but the formatt that I have is like 0.234.234.234.123.5434
What I Need is the Format like this 0,23452342234234234

```kotlin
private fun formatRowData(x: Float,
                            y: Float,
                            z: Float,
                            length: Double,
                            angle: Double): String {
    return String.format(
           "${SimpleDateFormat("H:m:s:SSS")
                .format(today.time)};$x;${y};${z};${length};${angle}",  Locale.GERMANY
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var value:String  ="0.234.234.234.123.5434"
value = value.replaceFirst(".", ",")
value = value.replace(".","")

println(" : "+value)
```

Output :

```
 : 0,2342342341235434
```